# Changing Hover on a weird button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello I'm having issues with a button of a Wordpress theme. The theme allow you to change the main color of a button but not the hover. I tried to change in css but it got super messy.

This is the code for the button

```
<a class="button light button_right button_size_2 button_js kill_the_icon" href="http:/" style="background-color:#fff!important;color:#1e325b;">
 <span class="button_icon">
  <i class="icon-check" style="color:#1e325b!important;"></I>
 </span>
 <span class="button_label">Prenota</span>
</a>
```

I tried adding this, but I only get the result in the image. It changes only the middle part...

```
a.button.light.button_right.button_size_2.button_js.kill_the_icon :hover {   
 background: orange;
}
```

[image]

how can I change the whole color?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
    a.button.light.button_right.button_size_2.button_js.kill_the_icon:hover > span{
    background: orange;
}
```

or for a more specific way

```
a.button.light.button_right.button_size_2.button_js.kill_the_icon:hover > span.button_label{
    background: orange;
}
a.button.light.button_right.button_size_2.button_js.kill_the_icon:hover > span.button_icon{
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: thanks David, it almost worked... https://ibb.co/6ZLB0rr here is what happen! looks like the border radius is white, but I have no idea on how to change. I tried doing border-color: orange but didn't work

Comment: hey rita, could you send me a bigger part of the code because I don't  understand where the white part comes from (Maybe also a Screenshot of the CSS Reference https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference so I can see what disturbs your Button 
Wish you also a happy new year ;)